# when finding a specific word and breaking

Tags: java, string, find, break, cpu-word

I am scanning an input string from user. and when the user enter #END command in string, program will break and it will show output.How can i overcome this?

for example;

> Pay attention to how notes are taken. For instance, I can put #END
>   here, and it won't save the rest.

output:

> Pay attention to how notes are taken. For instance, I can put

Comment: Can you show us some code you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way would be

```
  String input = "Pay attention to how notes are taken. For instance, I can put #END here, and it won't save the rest.";

  String [] out = input.split ("#END");

  System.out.println (out[0]);
```

If coming from user use `Scanner` class.

Comment: it must be come from user as an input

Comment: I have added some to my answer, but I am not going to write the whole code for you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); String input = scan.nextLine();` There ya go.